# I Want To Edit Some Files In C:\Program Files\WindowsApps Folder

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, uwp, files-folders

I Want To Edit Some Files In C:\Program Files\WindowsApps Folder But I Cant Do So.
I Changed The Owner To Everyone And Also Given Every User Full Access. But When I Try To Edit Files Or Create Some New Files I Cant. It Shows Me Error. Please Help Me.
I Think This Is Due To The Entry In win://sysappid Which Is Shown As Curropted.
If Yes, Then Please Tell How Can I Fix It.

Comment: Best advice : DON'T do that! Although it seems to be too late.

Answer (score 0):

That is a highly secured folder (Microsoft Apps) and you cannot edit in there. In a properly set up machine, that is not possible.  Permission is denied to users including Admin users.

You can uninstall / install apps in there with Power Shell.

If you have already made irreversible changes, the best advice now is to back everything up and re-install Windows 10.